# Solutions to Laplace's equation between surfaces of a constant coordinate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-learning, physics, boundary-value-problem

In Physics (specifically electrostatics) it is often encountered that one must solve the Dirichlet problem for Laplace's equation

\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 \varphi(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0
\end{equation}

between two surfaces of a constant coordinate, on each of which $\varphi$ is a different constant value. For example:

- Two concentric spheres with radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ ($R_1 \ne R_2$) where $\varphi$ is given to be two different constant values on these surfaces. In spherical coordinates, at the surface of the plates, $\varphi$ is independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$, and it just so happens that the solution of Laplace's equation for $\varphi$ between the spheres is also independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$.
- Two parallel-infinite planes separated by a distance where $\varphi$ is given to be two different constant values on these surfaces. In cartesian coordinates, at the surface of the plates, $\varphi$ is independent of $x$ and $y$, and it just so happens that the solution of Laplace's equation for $\varphi$ between the plates is also independent of $x$ and $y$.
- Two intersecting planes separated by an angular distance where $\varphi$ is given to be two different constant values on these surfaces. In cylindrical coordinates (with the z-axis defined along the line where the planes intersect), at the surface of the plates, $\varphi$ is independent of $r$ and $z$, and it just so happens that the solution of Laplace's equation for $\varphi$ between the plates is also independent of $r$ and $z$.

Is there a formal theorem that says something similar to:

> In a region bounded by two different surfaces of a constant coordinate, if $\nabla^2\varphi=0$ within the region and $\varphi$ is constant over both surfaces, then $\varphi$ within the region can only be a function of the coordinate used to define the constant surfaces.

?

Comment: I can see a way to do it using probability theory; the idea is that the solution to the Dirichlet problem $u(x)$ is $E_x[f(W(\tau))]$, where $W$ is a Wiener process, $E_x$ is mathematical expectation for the distribution of Wiener paths started at $x$, $f$ is the function on the boundary, and $\tau$ is the first time for the Wiener process to hit the boundary. Then everything seems to work out using symmetry properties of the Wiener process, since the expectation depends only on the probability to hit one piece of the boundary vs. the other. I'm not sure how to do it using ordinary PDE theory.

Comment: Is there some possibility in using Green's functions/identities?